# Reconfigure RAID-1 Virtual Disk managed by Dell Perc 4/SC controller

Tags: raid, virtual-disk

I'm running out of space on a server. It's got 3 SCSI drives connected to it managed by PERC 4/SC controller. One disk (let's call it #1) is 38Gb, the other two (#2 and #3) are 64Gb.

I have a RAID-1 Virtual Disk configured for disks #1 and #2, with disk #3 being a hot spare. Naturally, only 38Gb are available for the system. I know I can use 64 gig if I reconfigure Virtual Disk to use #2 and #3.

If I take disk #1 offline from the GUI manager and add disk #3 to the Virtual Disk, would it rebuild automatically? How do I make sure I don't loose data? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this, but.

1. Check if your backups are up to date.
2. Check if you can actually read these backups.
   Both step 1 and 2 should not be needed. But play this safe and test these.
3. Pull one of the drives. Either via the GUI manager, from a running machine or during a power down.
4. Rebuild the array. This should be automatic. With a mirror/RAID-1 this should be relative quick.

You now have a 64Gb drive with a 38GB (36?) filesystem. Next you want to expand the volume in the larger drive, or add a second volume. Else you have more space, but it will still be unused by the OS.

Comment: Thanks Hennes, I will check the backups. You're saying I can pull the drive via GUI on a running machine, rebuild on RAID-1 is done without a powerdown either... Is it possible to perform all of this over remote desktop? The server is in another location. Can I expand the same way? Any pitfalls I might be missing? Thanks again!

Comment: The pitfall I have seen twice in the last month is that **only** the first drive was set up to boot. The other drives had copies of all the data, but not of everything. (Last post no MBR and no Grub, older post not windows 100mb /boot partition). Double check if you can boot from the remaining drive.  If possible also check if your can access the host via DRAC, iLO or other server typo remote management. If you lack those make sure someone is on site. Hopefully unneeded, but it is best to be prepared.)